# com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Found two getters or fields with conflicting case sensitivity for property: name

Tags: java, android

Can Anyone check if there are error in my code

> ```
> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Found two getters or fields with conflicting case sensitivity for property: name
> ```

```
    ****package com.andisofttechnology.foodapp.model;
**
* Created by fullfocus on 8/25/2018.
*/
      public class User {
            public String Name,Password;
            public User(){
            }
            public User(String name,String password){
                Name = name;
                Password = password;
            }
            public String getName() {
                return Name;
            }
            public void setName(String name) {
                Name = name;
            }
            public String getPassword() {
                return Password;
            }
            public void setPassword(String password) {
                Password = password;
            }
        }


     com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Found two getters or fields with conflicting case sensitivity for property: name

      SignIn.java

            package com.andisofttechnology.foodapp;

            import android.app.ProgressDialog;
            import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
            import android.os.Bundle;
            import android.view.View;
            import android.widget.Button;
            import android.widget.EditText;
            import android.widget.Toast;

            import com.andisofttechnology.foodapp.model.User;
            import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
            import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
            import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
            import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
            import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
            import com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialAutoCompleteTextView;
            import com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText;

             com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Found two getters or fields with conflicting case sensitivity for property: name

            public class SignIn extends AppCompatActivity {
            EditText edtPhone,edtPassword;
                Button btnSignIn;
                @Override
                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in);
                    edtPassword = (MaterialEditText) findViewById(R.id.edtPassword);
                    edtPhone = (MaterialEditText)findViewById(R.id.edtPhone);
                    btnSignIn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSignIn);
                    //Init FireBase
                    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                    final DatabaseReference table_user = database.getReference("User");
                    btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            final ProgressDialog mDialog = new ProgressDialog(SignIn.this);
                            mDialog.setMessage("Please waiting...");
                            mDialog.show();

                            table_user.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                                    //Check if user not exist in database
                                    if(dataSnapshot.child(edtPhone.getText().toString()).exists()) {

                                        //Get User Information
                                        mDialog.dismiss();
                                        User user = dataSnapshot.child(edtPhone.getText().toString()).getValue(User.class);
                                        if (user.getPassword().equals(edtPassword.getText().toString())) {
                                            Toast.makeText(SignIn.this, "Sign in sucessfully !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        } else {
                                            Toast.makeText(SignIn.this, "Sign in failed !!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }

                                        }else {
                                        mDialog.dismiss();
                                        Toast.makeText(SignIn.this,"User  not exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            //Please check I Have a mistakes somewhere
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            }***
```

Comment: its working,thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Found two getters or fields with conflicting case sensitivity for
>   property: name

Your User **`MODEL`** class will be.

```
public class User {
            private String name,password;
            private User(){
            }
            public User(String name,String password){
                name = name;
                password = password;
            }
            public String getName() {
                return name;
            }
            public void setName(String name) {
                name = name;
            }
            public String getPassword() {
                return password;
            }
            public void setPassword(String password) {
                password = password;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change

`Name` to `name`

`Password` to `password`

in general, firebase using standard Java naming so you need to start any variable with small letter cases